# Excel Security Warning and and Visual Basic Runtime Error '1004' on .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False statement in QueryTables.Add Method

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA command is giving me a problem

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "text;https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/c_disagg.txt" _
    , Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))

    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
```

Although the application previously worked, I now get the following errors

1. Microsoft Excel Security Warning
   Certificate error
   (x) The application experienced an internal error loading the SSL libraries

followed by a highlighted error on line

.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

2. Microsoft Visual Basic Run-time error '1004'
   Excel cannot find the text file to refresh the external data range.
   Check to make sure the text file has not been moved or renamed, then try to refresh again.

I copied and pasted https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/c_disagg.txt into a browser window and the file exists and is displayed.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated since the application simply stopped working recently and yet it have been working fine for a long time.

I made certain the file the program was trying to access existed and then I did rather extensive Google searches on the problem, which appears not to be an uncommon one, but nothing I found or tried has resolved the issue.

Comment: How about retrieve data with Power Query ( Excel Ribbon: Data > From Web )

Answer (score 0):

- Get the data with Power Query and QueryTable

```vb
Sub GetTxtUrl()
    Dim oQry, qryTab As QueryTable
    Const URL = "https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/c_disagg.txt"
    Const QRY = "disagg" ' modify as needed
    ' Remove existing queries
    For Each oQry In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
        oQry.Delete
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QRY, Formula:= _
        "let Source=Csv.Document(Web.Contents(""" & URL & _
        """),[Delimiter="","", Encoding=936, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])" _
        & " in Source"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set qryTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & _
            QRY & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    If qryTab Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With qryTab
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & QRY & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = QRY
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ' Convert table (ListObject) to Range if needed
    With ActiveSheet
        .ListObjects(1).Unlist
        .Rows(1).Delete ' Remove header row
    End With
End Sub
```